# Pandas: Remove all rows between two specific strings in column, but only if a certain condition for that row is met

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a table like this:

| event | value |
| --- | --- |
| seed | 57 |
| ghy | 869 |
| repo | 5324 |
| repo | null |
| repo | null |
| trans | 32 |
| harv | 12 |
| weig | 6995 |
| repo | 45 |
| repo | null |

For this table, I need to find and remove all records between `seed` and `trans` events, that match the conditions: event column is equal `repo` and value column is not null.

As a result, I want to get the table:

| event | value |
| --- | --- |
| seed | 57 |
| ghy | 869 |
| repo | null |
| repo | null |
| trans | 32 |
| harv | 12 |
| weig | 6995 |
| repo | 45 |
| repo | null |

Many thanks.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I guess you can do something like this (MWE):

```
import pandas as pd
from io import StringIO

my_file = '''event  value
seed    57
ghy 869
repo    5324
repo    null
repo    null
trans   32
harv    12
weig    6995'''

df = pd.read_csv(StringIO(my_file), sep='\t')

df = df.drop(df.set_index('event')
       .loc['seed':'trans'].reset_index()
       .query('(event == "repo")&(value == value)').index)
```

Answer (score -1):

Let's say your *DataFrame* is `df`, so:

```
mask = df.values.notnull() & (df.event == 'repo') # notnull 'repo' values
mask[-2] = False # to not drop the last two rows
df_result = df[~mask] # keep the rows that does not match the conditions
```

I am not sure because I do not have you data, but the idea is to use a Boolean array (`mask`) to filter the rows (don't) want.

Comment: Hi, thanks for the answer, but this doesn't quite work, because I may have other repo events (e.g. at the end of the table, I just edited the description to show you) and want to they will still visible. I only want to get rid of those that are between "seed" and "trans" events.